# Why is my max value on a 16 bit image 65280?

Tags: python, numpy, tiff

I am using Python to read 16-bit image tiff files and find that my max value for all of my tiff files is 62580. This number is exactly 2^16 - 256 which I don't think is a coincidence but I can't make sense of why I don't see 2^16 or 2^16-1 being my max value.

Will the max value of a 16-bit image in Python ever get to be 2^16? Is this an artifact of my image or is this consistent with the way in which Python reads files? For reference I am using `tifffile.py` at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/ to read my images and convert them to numpy arrays.

Comment: Why do you think the maximum value in your image must be 2^16-1?  How was the image created?

Comment: provide a link to your image so I can try it

Comment: As you noted, 65280 = 255*256, so here is some pure speculation: your files were scaled up to 16 bit by multiplying 8 bit values by 256.  Are all the other values multiples of 256 (or equivalently, are all the low bytes of the 16 bit values zero)?

Comment: Could this be an ICC Lab file, which is a mix of signed and unsigned values corresponding to the CIELab color space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space), instead of the RGB values you may be expecting?  If so there may be useful info here, https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/lab2uint16.html , for example "Values are integers in the range [0, 65280]. L* values are multiplied by 65280/100. 
32768 is added to both the a* and b* values, which are represented as integers in the range [0,65535]." You won't be able to display the L* a* b* values like you would RGB values.